# Sort a text file, a (possible) leading ";" should be ignored, but retained in the output

Tags: shell, sorting, sed, awk

The expert help needed please:

File1:
;1002 Desc1002
;1001 Desc1001
207 Desc207
205 Desc205
;6 Desc6
2010 Desc2010
;2011 Desc2011

Output should be sorted **numerically**:

;6 Desc6
205 Desc205
207 Desc207
;1001 Desc1001
;1002 Desc1002
2010 Desc2010
;2011 Desc2011

(If a **character** sort is easier to do, producing the following output, oh well... it'll do)

;1001 Desc1001
;1002 Desc1002
2010 Desc2010
;2011 Desc2011
205 Desc205
207 Desc207
;6 Desc6

Is it possible to insert **leading zeros** to the output? So the output would look like:

;000006 Desc6
000205 Desc205
000207 Desc207
;001001 Desc1001
;001002 Desc1002
002010 Desc2010
;002011 Desc2011

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/^;\?\([0-9]*\)/\1\t&/' file | sort -n | sed 's/.*\t//'
;6 Desc6
205 Desc205
207 Desc207
;1001 Desc1001
;1002 Desc1002
2010 Desc2010
;2011 Desc2011
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F";" '{print $1 $2 "|" $0}' fileName | sort -n | cut -d"|" -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert leading zero's and keep the `;` in play, like this:

`awk '$1 ~ /^;/ ? sub(/^;/, "", $1) && $1 = ";"sprintf( "%06d", $1 ) : $1 = sprintf( "%06d", $1 )' file.txt`

So to give you the desired output, (and if you don't mind two consecutive `awk` calls), you can quickly join it up with amit_g's answer:

`awk '$1 ~ /^;/ ? sub(/^;/, "", $1) && $1 = ";"sprintf( "%06d", $1 ) : $1 = sprintf( "%06d", $1 )' file.txt | awk -F";" '{print $1 $2 "|" $0}' | sort -n | cut -d "|" -f 2`

Output:

```
;000006 Desc6
000205 Desc205
000207 Desc207
;001001 Desc1001
;001002 Desc1002
002010 Desc2010
;002011 Desc2011
```

HTH